# Magento get parent category and all his sub categories

Tags: php, magento

This is my category tree:

```
Cat_1 (This is the parent category with ID 4)
    Subcat_1
    Subcat_2
        Subsubcat_1
        Subsubcat_2
    Subcat_3
        Subsubcat_3
        Subsubcat_4
    Subcat_4
```

I tried this code to retrieve this category tree but i only came to the level of the subcats. I need one level deeper.

```
<?php
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
    foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
    {
          $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
          if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
              echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
          }
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<ul><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
    $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
    foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
    {
          $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
          if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
              echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
              $sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
              $sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_cat->getChildren();
              foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_subCatid)
              {
                $_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                }
              }
           }
     }
     echo '</ul>';
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Nina. That works! I just found out that also the first level is missing. Is it possible to start one level lower? Also, it would be great if the output is sorted correctly with the subcategories as a own UL in their parent category.

Comment: Edited the code. Just try. I did not test the code. If didnt work, echo the first level category appropriately. Also do some css to polish your result.

Comment: Almost! All the levels are visible now. Is it possible to have a structure like this? <ul><li>cat<ul>subcat</ul></li></ul>?

Comment: Just not quite what I mean, but I'll figure it out so. Thank you very much!